# How can I delete parts of a JSON web response?

Tags: json, perl

I have a simple Perl script and I want to remove everything up to the word "city". Or remove everything up to the nth occurrence (the 2nd in my particular case) of the comma's " , ". Here's what is looks like below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $CMD = `curl http://ip-api.com/json/8.8.8.8`;
chomp($CMD);
my $find = "^[^city]*city";

$CMD =~ s/$find//;

print $CMD;
```

The output is this:

```
{"as":"AS15169 Google Inc.","city":"Mountain View","country":"United States","countryCode":"US","isp":"Google","lat" :37.386,"lon":-122.0838,"org":"Google","query":"8.8.8.8","region":"CA","regionName":"California","status":"success","timezone":"America/Los_Angeles","zip":"94035"}
```

So i want do drop

```
" {"as":"AS15169 Google Inc.","
```

or drop up to

```
{"as":"AS15169 Google Inc.","city":"Mountain View",
```

## EDIT:

I see I was doing far too much when matching the string. I simplified the fix for my problem with removing all before "city". My $find has been changed to

```
my $find = ".*city";
```

While I also changed the replace function like so,

```
$CMD =~ s/$find/city/;
```

Still haven't figured out how to remove all before the nth occurrence of a comma or any character / string for that matter.

Comment: Have you considered using an actual JSON parser? (Rather than hardcoding the assumption that `city` will be the second field, the assumption that `as` will not contain a comma, etc., etc., etc.)

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm

Comment: Thanks for the advice, ill check these out. Appreciate it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The content you get back is [JSON](http://www.json.org), so you can easily turn it into a Perl data structure, play with it, and even turn it back into JSON if you like. That's the point! And, it's so easy:

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Mojo::JSON qw(decode_json encode_json);

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $tx = $ua->get( 'http://ip-api.com/json/8.8.8.8' );
my $json = $tx->res->body;

my $perl = decode_json( $json );

delete $perl->{'as'};

my $new_json = encode_json( $perl );

print $new_json;
```

[Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/) is wonderful for this. It's my preferred way for dealing with JSON even without the user-agent stuff. If you play with the JSON string directly, you're likely to have problems when the order of elements change or it contains wide characters.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to manually `decode_json()` with Mojolicious. Simply do this:

```
my $tx   = $ua->get('http://ip-api.com/json/8.8.8.8');
my $json = $tx->res->json;
my $as   = $json->{as}
```

You can even go fancy with JSON pointers:

```
my $as = $tx->res->json("/as");
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $results = `curl http://ip-api.com/json/8.8.8.8`;
chomp $results;
$results =~ s/^.*city":"\w+\s?\w+",//g;

print $results . "\n";
```

should do the trick.. unless there's a misunderstanding of what you want to keep v.s. remove.

FYI, http://regexr.com/ is totally my go to for regex happiness.

Comment: Thanks for the reference material, ill read up and see if I can it down. Your example is actually doing both actions, but i can dissect it and figure out from there =).  The overall goal would be to do 1 or the other, and i would use other logic to decide when i want them to occur

Comment: Don't do this. If the output comes back in a different order, you are screwed.